# Aggressive comments

Tags: discussion

Why is this user allowed (and encouraged) to make comments like this:

[wtf, you're copying answers again?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/670307/how-to-transliterate-characters-with-a-wildcard/670313?noredirect=1#comment1263986_670313)

An unsubstantiated claim.

---

In my opinion:

That is an unsubstantiated claim just because he is only interested in getting upvotes.  That is all he cares about. To that end he raise any complaint he can to mud the waters.

And the moderators do nothing, they even promote such activity.

#### Edit:

A question that I am pretty sure that I will regret making:

What is in my answer that is identical to ilkkachu answer?

Answer: Nothing!!

Sure, the *Repeat SET1 characters.* may look similar. Sure you will argue that a missing 26 number is an small change, and that that is exactly what he wrote.

Not saying that that only works in GNU `tr` and that there is no need for the 26 (even in POSIX) is no improvement ? Isn't that a helpful addition ?

In any case, my answer is **not** a copy, it is different.

Opinions, that is the only thing remaining.

---

### Result:

And the user got what he wanted: some upvotes on his answer, some downvotes on mine. Great team work! Keep it up!

## To Terdon

As he claims that:

> I will add that it seems odd that you are complaining about unsubstantiated allegations in a post that makes two such unsubstantiated (and false) allegations: no user is "encouraged" to post rude comments in any way, and the mod team most certainly doesn't "promote such activity".

@terdon Let's review some facts. Before ilkkachu posted his comment we had the same upvotes in our answers. Very quickly after I raised a flag on that comment, the votes went to 6 for ilkkachu and 3 for me. Someone downvoted my answer. The ilkkachu answer got downvoted **and** up-voted. Who comes *very quickly* to review answers after they are flagged? Answer: Mods. So, it stand to reason that mods up-voted the answer of he who used an aggressive comment and downvoted the answer of who received such comment. In short: mods encouraged such behaviour.

Comment: Mods cannot check all possible comments posted on the site. Instead, did you flag the comment? Also, your comment reply doesn't really help and may worsen the situation. *Just flag and move on*.

Comment: @AndrewT. Of course I flagged it, before posting here !.

Comment: PSA: both comments have now been deleted.

Comment: I will add that it seems odd that you are complaining about unsubstantiated allegations in a post that makes two such unsubstantiated (and false) allegations: no user is "encouraged" to post rude comments in any way, and the mod team most certainly doesn't "promote such activity".

Comment: @terdon Dime de que te jactas y te dire en que fallas.

Comment: @ImHere this isn’t Spanish, but “We see things not as they are, but as we are ourselves.”

Comment: @StephenKitt Exactly ! Exactly what I am saying !!.

Comment: Since the comments have now been deleted, anyone interested can find a screenshot here: https://i.imgur.com/hPvELcP.png

Comment: @terdon Read the edit. I sure hope you could step out of your righteous position for a moment and actually **see** what is happening.

Comment: @terdon Posting images help in which way?

Comment: Not sure what righteous position you're talking about. But you have posted about a rude comment which has been deleted since you are quite right that it was rude, so I posted a screenshot of both the original comment and your (also deleted) response so users can see the context. Otherwise, they could think you are lying since there is no comment.

Comment: For what it's worth, I haven't cast a single vote on any of the questions or answers on that page. I downvoted _this_ post since you are slinging false accusations around, but didn't vote one way or the other on the post you are referring to. All I did was delete the rude comment you had flagged, as requested.

Comment: @ImHere I'm confused. Can you explain when ilkkachu posted the comment, and when you flagged it? The problem in understanding the situation is that _both_ answers were up- _and downvoted_ today, and the vote summary for yesterday already showed +6/-0 for ilkkachus answer and +5/-1 for yours...

Comment: @terdon Yes, you may not have voted, but you have assigned guilt quite quickly: you said: *two such unsubstantiated (and false) allegations*. Quick to judge, fast to assign guilt.

Comment: Well yes, of course. You claimed, falsely, that moderators encourage users to post rude comments (we don't, we actively discourage them) and that we even "promote such activity". These are patently false allegations whose falseness I know since I am a mod. So yes, when someone accuses me of doing something I did not do, I judge the accusation as false.

Comment: @AdminBee I am commenting from memory, I may be wrong (I hope  am not). But where do you see such summary? In any case, the image posted by terdon have a time for each comment, maybe that could help?

Comment: I did NOT accused YOU directly, but the analysis I just made shows strong indication that mods (in general) did. @terdon  That is exactly your righteous position: I did nothing wrong, never, ever, so all mods are also clean and well. Maybe they are, but just maybe, they are not.

Comment: @ImHere You probably know the "Show activity on this post"-icon  (a small analog clock) next to each question, below the vote arrows. By default, the vote counts are not displayed in that view, but you can click on "Show vote summaries" and it gives a summary of all votes (up and down separately) for each day. Not time-resolved; I assume because this would somewhat reduce the vote anonymity.

Comment: @AdminBee mods can see a daily summary of the votes cast on a post (although not by whom). I can see that in the 24h period of the 23d of September, ImHere's answer had received 5 upvotes and one downvote, and the answer received another 2 downvotes and one more upvote in the 24h period of the 24th of September. The competing answer had received 6 upvotes and no downvotes on the 23rd and received 2 up and 2 down on the 24th. I'm afraid we cannot know with any more detail than that, we only get daily summaries, but yes, the OP's answer did get 2 downvotes today.

Comment: Oh. Cool, @AdminBee, I wasn't sure if non-mods could see that.

Comment: I did all my voting on those answers yesterday, and I have not downvoted your answer @ImHere. By posting a Meta post about the question and its answers, you are naturally funneling more people to the Q/As.  More people means more votes. The comment that this current issue is about has been deleted, so the issue seems to have gone away. Is there something else that needs to be discussed here?

Comment: @terdon Yeah, if I remember correctly it came somewhere around a few thousand reputation (but I don't remember exactly when).

Comment: @AdminBee Yes, I can see the votes now. Yes, mine had 5 up and 1 down registered at 11 hours ago. Well, that is not how I remember that. I saw that our answers were close, and mine was very, very short, so I decided to expand and improve on it. It got 2483 characters 7 hour ago (quite a lot) and later this discussion got started. I might be remembering incorrectly, or remembering a look to an older situation. What history says is what the logs show. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Kusalananda The comments are here, in the image that terdon posted. There is nothing else to be added, I believe, all the facts have been already posted. Just hope things improve in the future.

Comment: That question has 600+ views now; even if half of them came after this meta post, that still leaves literally hundreds of users who could have voted on the answers based on whatever their own opinions and biases are. Some downvotes are hardly proof that the moderators are unfairly in league with a particular user to boost that user's rep. And then there's the question of why you'd assume the mods would be in such a league specifically with a user who also doesn't tend to avoid speaking their mind when they disagree with the moderators...

Answer (score 7):

As Andrew T said, if you see a comment that's against the [Code of Conduct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/conduct), please flag it. If you see constructive criticism in a comment, do your best to provide a technical response: either as an edit to the post followed by flagging that comment as no longer needed, or as another comment. Responding with words like "pick a fight", "persecution", or "bullying" is only going to escalate the situation to no good end.

Separately, both of you have enough rep to be unconcerned with 3 votes this way or that way. Since the question hit the HNQ, expect the voting to be swayed *anyway*. That's *before* the Meta viewers see this and visit the question.

Everyone: Please keep your focus on providing high-quality content and abiding by the site's rules.